# nHibernate QueryOver<T> Complication

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lambda, queryover

I have the following tables:

Customer => CustomerAccount => Account

I have an nHibernate mapped POCO to each of the tables above as well.

I have the following lambda expression in an object which implements `IIdentifier<T>`

```
public Expression<Func<ICustomer, bool>> Filter
{
    get { return customer => customer.CustomerNumber == _customerNumber; }
}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is join the Customer => CustomerAccount => Account tables via a `QueryOver<Account>`

How do I add the above `Filter` lamdba, which is of type Customer, to filter by the customer number?

```
ICustomer customer = null;
ICustomerAccount customerAccount = null;
IAccount account = null;

var query = QueryOver(() => account)
    .JoinAlias(() => account.CustomerAccounts, () => customerAccount, JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .JoinAlias(() => customerAccount.Customer, () => customer, JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .Where(() => customerAccount.EndDate == null)
    .And(() => account.IsPreferredAccount == true)
    .And(() => ?? Want to add the above Filter() lambda some how here);
```

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
var query = QueryOver(() => account)
    .JoinAlias(() => account.CustomerAccounts, () => customerAccount, JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .JoinAlias(() => customerAccount.Customer, () => customer, JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .Where(() => customerAccount.EndDate == null)
    .And(() => account.IsPreferredAccount == true)
    .And(Restrictions.Where<ICustomer>(Filter));
```